# running multiple emulators using android avd manager cli

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

Can anyone please tell me how I can run both at the same time? I open my avd using `android avd` I can start my first emulator, when I try and run a second, it opens but I just get a black screen. Can I run both at the same time by starting them from my `avd manager`?

Comment: You may need to adjust how much memory you have allocated for HAX and make sure that both emulators are using only the available memory.

Comment: Is there a certain way to go about it? I'm trying to change the ram for each emulator and my machine just freezes,